# SQL Server - PIVOT values of all columns under two columns

Tags: sql-server

So, I have the below table structure:

```
ID    Autor1             Autor2  Autor3 Redactor1 Redactor2 CategorieDeVarsta1  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Ursula K. Le Guin      a     c        a          c        14-15 ani
2    Natalie Babbitt        b     d        b          d        12-13 ani
```

I would like that all the column headers name (Autor1, Autor2 etc.) to go under one column, let's say `Code` and the values of each column to go under a second column. Is this possible? I tried with `PIVOT` and `CROSS APPLY` and couldn't do it. Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to UnPivot?

```
Select  ID, Code, Val  
From  (Select id, Autor1, Autor2, Autor3, Redactor1, Redactor2, CategorieDeVarstal From autor) p
UnPivot
  (Val FOR Code IN (Autor1, Autor2, Autor3, Redactor1, Redactor2, CategorieDeVarstal)
  ) AS unpvt
```

Result:

```
ID  Code                    Val
1   Autor1                  Ursula K. Le Guin
1   Autor2                  a
1   Autor3                  c
1   Redactor1               a
1   Redactor2               c
1   CategorieDeVarstal      14-15 ani
2   Autor1                  Natalie Babbitt
2   Autor2                  b
2   Autor3                  d
2   Redactor1               b
2   Redactor2               d
2   CategorieDeVarstal      12-13 ani
```